# How to find Docker images that contain specific dependencies?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, cicd

For small projects, I sometimes would like to use existing Docker containers, but find it difficult to find relevant ones.

For example, if an R project depends on a few tidyverse packages, I could of course:

- either use the large [rocker/tidyverse](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse)
- or the small [rocker/r-base](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-base) & install the packages I need

However, is there a way to find existing packages that match what I need more closely? Searching publicly like `https://github.com/search?q=path%3ADockerfile+readr+dplyr+tidyr+ggplot2&type=code` helps a bit, but is there a ready-made tool to assist for such searches?

The goal would be to find popular, maintained images, that definitely contain a given set of dependencies, but as few others as possible.

Comment: I guess I'm also asking for another dropdown option "size", besides DockerHub's `Recently Updated`, `Suggested`  & `Best Match` sort options.